# How to use the most recently printed line as an input?

Tags: python, twitter, printing, bots, status

I am trying to create a Twitter bot that posts a random line from a text file. I have gone as far as generating the random lines, which print one at a time, and giving the bot access to my Twitter app, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use a printed line as a status.

I am using Tweepy. My understanding is that I need to use `api.update_status(status=X)`, but I don't know what `X` needs to be for the status to match the most recently printed line.

This is the relevant section of what I have so far:

```
from random import choice
x = 1
while True:
  file = open('quotes.txt')
  content = file.read()
  lines = content.splitlines()
  print(choice(lines))
  api.update_status(status=(choice(lines)))
  time.sleep(3600)
```

The bot is accessing Twitter no problem. It is currently posting another random quote generated by `(choice(lines))`, but I'd like it to match what prints immediately before.

Comment: X needs to be a string, as is mentioned in the API on [link](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html). Where are you printing the line? Show us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly printing a choice:

```
print(choice(lines))
```

create a new variable and use it in your `print()` and your `api.update_status()`:

```
selected_quote = choice(lines)
print(selected_quote)
api.update_status(status=selected_quote)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may not fully understand your question, but from the very top, where it says, "How to use the most recently printed line as an input", I think I can answer that. Whenever you use the print() command, store the argument into a string variable that overwrites its last value. Then it saves the last printed value.